# Deliver a Cocoapods Pod with UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, cocoapods, xib

I was wondering about the best way to deliver a Cocoapods Pod with UI.
I need the users of my Pod to be able to initialise an instance of some entry point view controller, and then presenting it in their app (for example with `presentViewController:animated:completion`).

I see three options:

1. Bundling `.xib` files for each UI (this will also make me use `.xib` files and not storyboards internally). This way the user initialises the first view controller and from there I take control.
2. Bundling a whole storyboard, but then how do you expect the user to integrate it into their app?
3. Building my UI programatically inside my Pod (like I saw [Braintree](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios) do in their SDK).

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would do the UI in code. Always. Not only in a Pod.

Comment: Really? with constraints and everything???

Comment: Sure. Not a problem. I do all my UIs in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of those options work just fine. If you choose to use xibs or storyboards you have to remember to include those files in your podspec like so:

```
  s.resources    = "Project/**/*.{png,jpeg,jpg,gif,storyboard,xib,lproj,xcdatamodeld,plist,xcassets}"
```

Also one thing to look out for is accessing your pod's bundle. It won't be the `NSBundle.mainBundle()` anymore since your pod doesn't have access to the main project's bundle. Instead you need to access the bundle for the class you are working in like so `let podBundle = NSBundle(forClass: self)`

Comment: Important note about the bundle!
How do you expect the user of my Pod to integrate if I deliver a storyboard? Or how do I load my 'entry point' view controller from a storyboard?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. If you are just trying to pass them view controllers, for example, then you could create public methods to retrieve them and then within those methods instantiate the view controller from your bundle and pass it back to them. So user/app needs view controller, user/app requests view controller from your pod. Your pod instantiates the view controller and gives it back to the user/app.